# Loading 3ds file in Qt4.6

Tags: qt4, opengl-es

I need to develop some application using OpenGL in Qt for Symbian platform. I found a function called loadScene in Qt3 that where used to load 3ds files but couldn't find any for the latest version of Qt.

Is there any library that I could use ?

Thanks,

Alexandre

Answer (score 2):

It is not Qt3. It is Qt3d. Both are entirely different.

From [Qt3d documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt3d-snapshot/qt3d-building.html#obtaining-and-building-qt-sources-for-qt-3d), **Qt/3D requires access to source files that do not ship with an SDK. Until Qt/3D becomes a regular part of Qt, either download an official [Qt 4.7 source package](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0-beta1.zip) , or a source tarball from our   [gitorious repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/).**

You may have to download the source files and configure it manually as given in the documentation.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

3DS files are supported using the open source lib3ds library. A copy of version 1.3 of this library is included with the Qt/3D sources under the 3rdparty directory.
Note we mean Qt/3D,not Qt3 :)